# Хостинг VPS Ubuntu14, 4Гб ОЗУ, nginx+mysql, SWAP оптимальный размер

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, vps, swap

Имеется хостинг VPS Ubuntu14, 4Гб ОЗУ, 4x2.27 GHz, nginx+mysql.
Интернет магазин с посещаемостью в сутки около 20 тыс. 
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness  60 
средняя загруженность ОЗУ 60-65% , размер SWAP 488444 kB
SWAP всегда заполнен почти полностью. 
Вопрос, 
1) есть ли смысл в данном случаи swappiness менять на 10, чтобы система больше использовала ОЗУ и переводила в Свап когда заполняется свыше 90%? 
2) Какой размер SWAP относительно оптимален в данном случаи?

Comment: Постановка вопроса не совсем верна. Надо смотреть на пиковые значения, а не средние

Comment: ОЗУ в течении всего дня 61-65% , не падает график и не поднимается.

Comment: Содержимое SWAP http://prntscr.com/pzwxap

Comment: 2XRAM / методика

Comment: да, по умолчанию в мануале часто указывается рекомендация SWAP размер в два раза больше объема RAM, но по  сути в итоге СВАП забивается и нагрузка на RAM будет такая же, вопрос лучшей производительности так же висит.